# DonorManagementTests does not have a default constructor (nunit/moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit, moq

I'm using moq with nunit and my test doesn't give me a fail or pass. It says it doesn't have a default constructor. I suspect I am not doing something correctly with injecting my interface into the constructor.

**DonorManagementTests**

```
[TestFixture]
public class DonorManagementTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IValidation> _mockValidation;
    private readonly DonorManagement _donorManagement;

    public DonorManagementTests(IValidation validation)
    {
        _mockValidation = new Mock<IValidation>();
        _donorManagement = new DonorManagement(_mockValidation.Object);

    }

    [Test, Description("View correct gift aid to two decimal places")]
    public void DonorViewGiftAid()
    {
        const int donation = 20;
        _mockValidation.Setup(x => x.ValidateDonation(donation)).Returns(20.00m);
        var res = _donorManagement.GiftAidAmount(donation);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof (decimal), res);
        _mockValidation.Verify(x => x.ValidateDonation(donation), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

**DonorManagement**

```
public class DonorManagement : IDonor
{
    private readonly IValidation _validation;

    public DonorManagement(IValidation validation)
    {
        _validation = validation;
    }

    public virtual decimal GiftAidAmount(decimal donationAmount)
    {
        const decimal gaRatio = 17.5m / (100 - 17.5m);
        return _validation.ValidateDonation(donationAmount) * gaRatio;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I need to change in my code?

Comment: Your constructor `DonorManagementTests` does not even use its parameter. You could remove it, `public DonorManagementTests() { ... }`. However, if you add more tests to the same class, be aware of what Old Fox said in his answer: When many tests are run together, the instance constructor runs only once. A method with the `[SetUp]` attribute, on the other hand, will run before each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your test class must have a default C'tor.

change your test class to:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DonorManagementTests
{
    private Mock<IValidation> _mockValidation;
    private DonorManagement _donorManagement;

    [SetUp]
    public TestInit()
    {
        _mockValidation = new Mock<IValidation>();
        _donorManagement = new DonorManagement(_mockValidation.Object);

    }

    [Test, Description("View correct gift aid to two decimal places")]
    public void DonorViewGiftAid()
    {
        const int donation = 20;
        _mockValidation.Setup(x => x.ValidateDonation(donation)).Returns(20.00m);
        var res = _donorManagement.GiftAidAmount(donation);
        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof (decimal), res);
        _mockValidation.Verify(x => x.ValidateDonation(donation), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

now each test will be isolated and you'll be able to execute your tests.

Comment: Adding a setup method is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit documentation (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5) says:

- A non-parameterized fixture must have a default constructor.
- A parameterized fixture must have a constructor that matches the parameters provided.